# spring mvc Proxy server - maintaining url context (contextpath)

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

I have the below piece spring REST controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/global")
public class ProxyController extends BaseController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**")
    public ResponseEntity<String> proxy(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws Exception {
        try {
            String restOfTheUrl = (String) request.getAttribute(
                    HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
            URL uri = new URL("https://myrealserver" +
                    restOfTheUrl);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            return resp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error ", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }   
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to hide a server behind a proxy, which blindly forwards requests to the server.

This piece of code is invoked with url

```
https://myproxyserver/myapp1/end/point1
```

which in turn returns an html page with few clickable links. Now when the user clicks I am expecting the link to be invoked as

```
https://myproxyserver/myapp1/end/point2
```

Where as actually the endpoint invoked is

```
   https://myproxyserver/end/point2
```

In the html page returned by the actual server, the path is end/point2 and has no mention of myapp1. So on click on those links my context changes to  https://myproxyserver/end/point2 instead of https://myproxyserver/myapp1/end/point2

How do I ensure that the root context is always https://myproxyserver/myapp1 and not https://myproxyserver ?

Comment: Append `request.getContext()` to the URL

Comment: sorry, did not get it. request.getContext() to which url? the HTML page being responded with has may links. do you mean I have to scan through the content and replace? The second request is not reaching this piece of code is my problem as context has changed. Is there no global setting i can do in the response which will allow me to set the contextpath?

Comment: Your html page is returned by server, right? If yes, where you add base url, you have to append the context of this application as well.

Comment: Yep. I took your advice and did that! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the problem by taking what D D suggested. I scanned through the whole response body, fortunately I had a pattern that I could use to scan and appended the context of the url to where ever required. That resolved the problem for me this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get your server context path. this is sample code.

like this :

```
public static String getServerNameAndContextPath(HttpServletRequest req) {
        return "https://" + req.getServerName() + req.getContextPath();
    }
```